# Which is best way to clean the innerHTML when working with dynamic content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What's the best way to clean the innerHTML of an element that is going to be changing over and over?

I made a small function that would clean the containers, but I do not think that's quite efficient enough. I mean it does work, but only with the containers  which it's told to, so maybe it is better to just make every element to rewrite its own innerHTML?

Comment: You should define what "clean" means.

Comment: Question is far too vague without some context

Answer (score 0):

Simpliest and most effective way :

```
function clear() {
          document.getElementById("yourElement").innerHTML = "";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Jquery you can set the content of an element with `.html()`.
It will simply override and replace the old html content.

```
$(".your-element").html("<p>your new content</p>");
```